# Convert JavaBean (in .java file) to a JSON file

Tags: java, json

I want to convert JavaBean to a JSON file. Please note the JavaBean should be read from actual .java file not through programmatically. To illustrate my point:

- There is a EmployeeBean.java in C:\Foo
- I want to read this java file and convert it into a JSON file.

Currently my steps are:

- Use Eclipse AST library to parse that file (if it is source code) or use ASM library if it is .class file
- Get the method(s) information and use JSONObject to create JSON manually.

But I am thinking this is an in-efficient way. So I am asking is there any efficient way to do this or is there any library available?

I tried to look for Google's GSON and Jackson, but I think it won't work with .java files. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Do you need the class definition or just the JSON representation of the object? If the 2nd apply, Jackson or Gson will help you.

Comment: I don't fully understand. JSON is a data format (like XML), so what result do you expect when converting source code? Can you give a simple example?

Comment: I think he wants the class definition. Is that correct, Pradeep Simha?

Comment: @SilviuBurcea correct.

Comment: You're not looking for JSON then. JSON is just the data, the properties without methods and constructors, which I believe you also want.

Comment: I guess you should provide some input and output samples. Also, is inheritance involved? What about interfaces?

Comment: @SilviuBurcea, ok. I will provide example.